# Display the current song title

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences

Hi I have a service for my music player. It contains a broadcastReceiver which updates the seekbar in my activity.I am displaying the song title using this method. I have got the expected results but it is good to update song title and albumArt.If not suggest me a alternative approach for this. Then other question is that how can I save the last played song when the activity is destroyed. I have used sharedPreference.I got the title but I can't set it to Textview. Can you please guide me? Please answer this questions!!!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can defenitly pull the song title out of shared preferences and assign it to your text view. Here is an example:

```
TextView text = findViewById(R.id.text);
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
if (restoredText != null) {
  String name = prefs.getString("name", "No name defined");//"No name defined" is the default value.
text.setText(name); 
}
```

Comment: If my guess is right. restoredText is the text I got from sharedPreference but what about name String? i tried your method but got null pointer exception

Comment: Can I use the same method to store my song's seek progress and play from the same position when the activity starts.